# Filter DataFrame rows with at least one value in list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `pandas` DataFrame structured as follows:

```
ID                                            Class
0  2431214                                   16,41,9
1  2497796                   14,16,18,20,24,35,41,42
2  1407550          20,21,24,25,26,27,28,3,34,35,4,8
3   472723                                   1,17,22
4   423046                     28,30,32,34,39,4,42,8
```

`Class` is a string attribute. I want to filter rows where `Class` contains at least one of the elements in a given list, for example, if my filter is `l = [16, 27]`, I should get the following:

```
ID                                            Class
0  2431214                                   16,41,9
1  2497796                   14,16,18,20,24,35,41,42
2  1407550          20,21,24,25,26,27,28,3,34,35,4,8
```

This behaviour I'm looking for is similar to SQL's `IN` statement, which works fine. However, `pandas`' `isin` is not working for me (it's returning entries with only exactly one of the filter classes):

```
l = [16, 27]
filtered = df.loc[df['Class'].isin(l)]
```

```
ID               Class
210   30359        16
945   46307        27
3641  81222        27
3817  77365        27
4185  89828        16
```

How can I filter my DataFrame so that entries with **at least** one value satisfying the filter condition are returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have strings, the most optimal is likely to use a regex with word boundaries:

```
pattern = '|'.join(map(str, l))

out = df[df['Class'].str.contains(fr'\b(?:{pattern})\b')]
```

Output:

```
        ID                             Class
0  2431214                           16,41,9
1  2497796           14,16,18,20,24,35,41,42
2  1407550  20,21,24,25,26,27,28,3,34,35,4,8
```

If you want to know which values were detected:

```
# first match
df['Class'].str.extract(fr'\b({pattern})\b', expand=False)
# all matches
df['Class'].str.extractall(fr'\b({pattern})\b')[0].groupby(level=0).agg(','.join)
```